# Gearman refusing to connect to mysql

Tags: gearman

```
gearmand  --queue-type=MySQL           --mysql-host=localhost           --mysql-port=3306           --mysql-user=user           --mysql-password=pass--mysql-db=gearman           --mysql-table=gearman_queue
```

Nets me the following error

```
gearmand: Error while initializing the queue : MySQL
```

What's strange is that I can access the database fine with the same credentials, currently running on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Actually I found out this was caused by an older version of MariaDB.  Checking the logs gave me the following error: 
 MySQL module: create table failed: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes.  Upgrading mariadb to 10.2 fixed this

Answer (score 0):

```
gearmand \
  --queue-type mysql \
  --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 \
  --mysql-user=XXX \
  --mysql-password=XXX \
  --mysql-db=gearman \
  --mysql-table=queue
```

[see also](https://github.com/gearman/gearmand/issues/4#issuecomment-231198939)